# Filtering out a specific word from logcat

Tags: eclipse, android-logcat

I would like to stop showing all logs with the tag "Trace". How do i create a filter that shows me everything else but that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting in the filter into the text field above the log (in your screenshot)?

Comment: I know how to do tag:xx, but not tag:(-yyy), where it shows me everything other than yyy

Answer (score 0):

using 
^(?!.*(TagToFilterOut)).*$

in the byLogTag field when create new filter